# cache and data on gradle 2.0

Tags: android, performance, caching, gradle

I have issues since i have upgrade to gradle 2.0

i have notice the start up time takes a lot before splash screen is shown , at the first time you run the application it could take 10 seconds of white screen .

i can avoid the white screen with :

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

but this is not really solve the problem  , after some research i have deleted all the application from my phone , deleted all the code in application class and in my SplashScreen class but the setContentView . and still....

1 . i takes a lot of time before splash screen appear
2 . i have notice that my data is about 8 mega and the cache is about 63 mega !!!

is this normal ?

what is happening in the background from the moment to launch application to the moment it start application class ?